# Как сделать постоянную проверку статуса сервера (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, ping

И так, есть сервер и нужно знать его состояние постоянно и асинхроннао...

Пробовал так, не получается(

```
Thread pingThread = new Thread(_client_PingServer);
pingThread.Start();

private void _client_PingServer()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(settingsControl1.txtIPAddress.Text);
                if (pingReply.RoundtripTime <= 70 && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= 1)
                {
                    labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
                else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime >= 70 && pingReply.RoundtripTime <= 120)
                {
                    labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
                }
                else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime >= 120)
                {
                    labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime == 0)
                {
                    labelServerStatus.Text = @"Offline";
                }
                if (pingReply.RoundtripTime != 0)
                {
                    labelServerStatus.Text = pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (PingException)
            {
                labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                labelServerStatus.Text = @"Offline";
            }
        }
```

**Ваши идеи?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала разберемся почему не работает. В первую очередь потому, что вы обращаетесь к свойствам UI-контролов из другого потока. Так нельзя, элементы UI доступны только из потока, в котором они созданы и обрабатываются, т.к. им необходимо слушать системные сообщения и реагировать на действия пользователя.

Вторая причина - код вашего метода, даже если исправить предыдущую ошибку не является циклическим, следовательно вполне логично, что он выполнится ровно один раз.

Самый простой способ периодического выполнения некоторого действия - воспользоваться таймером, т.к. простой цикл тут не годится.

У класса `Ping` есть асинхронный метод [Ping.SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh159414(v=vs.110).aspx), который делает все тоже самое. что и обычный `Ping.Send`, который вы использовали, только предназначен для асинхронного выполнения. Стандартный таймаут ping для Windows при недоступности узла составляет 4 сек. ([пруф](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb490968.aspx)), поэтому, если это имеет значение, придется выбрать другую перегрузку `Ping.SendAsync`, которая позволяет указать величину таймаута в параметрах при вызове метода.

Теперь соберем все вместе, чтобы получить желаемый результат. Для приложения WinForms, в качестве таймера будем использовать [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), т.к. с одной стороны, нам нужна возможность работать со свойствами контролов, а конкретно этот таймер исполняет обработчик в UI-потоке, с другой стороны, `SendAsync` нужно просто правильно вызвать, т.к. он уже использует асинхронность.

Добавление таймера и настройка его параметров документированы хорошо и с примерами кода, поэтому тут покажу только обработчик события [Timer.Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx), который и будет выполнять всю работу.

```
//помечаем обработчик ключевым словом async, чтобы получить возможность
//внутри вызывать асинхронные методы через await
async private void PingByTimer(object sender, EventArgs args) 
{
    try
    {
        var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        //асинхронно выполняем Ping
        var pingReply = await ping.SendPingAsync(settingsControl1.txtIPAddress.Text);
        //после получения результата мы снова в UI-потоке и продолжаем.
        if (pingReply.RoundtripTime <= 70 && pingReply.RoundtripTime >= 1)
        {
            labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime > 70 && pingReply.RoundtripTime <= 120)
        {
            labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime > 120)
        {
            labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else if (pingReply.RoundtripTime == 0)
        {
            labelServerStatus.Text = @"Offline";
        }
        if (pingReply.RoundtripTime != 0)
        {
            labelServerStatus.Text = pingReply.RoundtripTime.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        labelServerStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        labelServerStatus.Text = @"Offline";
    }
}
```

Осталось подписаться этим методом на событие `Tick` и активировать таймер, например, после удачного первого подключения к серверу. Как видите, изменения в вашем коде минимальны, но при этом все работает.

Comment: А есть самый не простой, но очень хороший способ?)

Comment: @MiT Не стоит усложнять без крайней необходимости. Если код получился простым - это хорошо. В чем вы видите проблему?

Comment: Ну ладно. `Осталось подписаться этим методом на событие Tick`, а как это сделать?

Comment: @MiT также как и на любое другое событие. Кидаете таймер на форму, он доступен в панельке. там же где кнопки и прочие контролы. Выбираете. Переключаете отображение свойств на отображение событий и в нужном событии выбираете или вписываете этот метод. Почитайте ссылки в ответе, там все с официальными примерами кода от MS.